# Bootstrap Footer columns not aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, footer

I'm trying to get each header to aligning in their individual columns by using `col-sm-3`, however I don't seem to be getting any luck.

This is an image of a footer similar to show what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQmy2.png]

```css
.footer {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.footer-title h6 {
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home </title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon_head.ico" />



  <!-- Google fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>



<body>
  <!--NAVIGATION-->




  <div class="container-bg-signup">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="signup">
            <div class="signup text-center">
              <h4>JOIN OUR MAILING LIST!</h4>
              <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
                <input type="email" id="myEmail" value="enter your email">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-light-orange btn-sign">SUBSCRIBE</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <footer class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="footer">
          <div id="cat-1">
            <h6 class="footer-title">About
              <h6>
                <ul>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>About Company</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Vison & Mission</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Parnters</li><a/>
                        <a href="###">
                          <li>Policy</li><a/>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div id="cat-2">
            <h6 class="footer-title">Useful Links</h6>
            <ul>
              <a href="###">
                <li>Help</li> <a/>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>testimonials</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Store Location</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Trade Account</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Site Map</li><a/>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div id="cat-3">
            <h6 class="footer-title">Customers</h6>
            <ul>
              <a href="###">
                <li>Our Prices</li><a/>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Returns</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Sizes</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Regster</li><a/>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div id="cat-4">
            <h6 class="footer-title">Documentation</h6>
            <ul>
              <a href="###">
                <li>RISQS Certificate</li><a/>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Insurance</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Libray</li><a/>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebiSS/tbo2h5cy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, and that you want all four of the col-sm-3 columns in the footer tag to align? Then remove the extra `<div class="footer">` you've put in the code, because you're already calling the `.footer` class in your top div. Like so: `<footer class="container-fluid footer">`

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
<footer class="container-fluid footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <!-- REMOVE --> <div class="footer"> 
            <div id="cat-1">
              <h6 class="footer-title">About
                <h6>
                  <ul>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>About Company</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Vison & Mission</li><a/>
                        <a href="###">
                          <li>Parnters</li><a/>
                          <a href="###">
                            <li>Policy</li><a/>
                  </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-2">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Useful Links</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Help</li> <a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>testimonials</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Store Location</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Trade Account</li><a/>
                        <a href="###">
                          <li>Site Map</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-3">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Customers</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Our Prices</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Returns</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Sizes</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Regster</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-4">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Documentation</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>RISQS Certificate</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Insurance</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Libray</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

NEW CODE:

```
<footer class="container-fluid footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-1">
              <h6 class="footer-title">About
                <h6>
                  <ul>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>About Company</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Vison & Mission</li><a/>
                        <a href="###">
                          <li>Parnters</li><a/>
                          <a href="###">
                            <li>Policy</li><a/>
                  </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-2">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Useful Links</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Help</li> <a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>testimonials</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Store Location</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Trade Account</li><a/>
                        <a href="###">
                          <li>Site Map</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-3">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Customers</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>Our Prices</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Returns</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Sizes</li><a/>
                      <a href="###">
                        <li>Regster</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="cat-4">
              <h6 class="footer-title">Documentation</h6>
              <ul>
                <a href="###">
                  <li>RISQS Certificate</li><a/>
                  <a href="###">
                    <li>Insurance</li><a/>
                    <a href="###">
                      <li>Libray</li><a/>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!! This may sound a bit stupid but what class do I selected if I want to start styling the footer?

Comment: Depends on which part you'd like to style? If it's the entire footer than the .footer class would work i.e. <footer class="container-fluid footer"> this <footer> tag is the entire thing.

Comment: That's what I have tried but I'm not getting any results

Comment: Just the background colour

Comment: Ok, to change the background you need to edit this section: .footer {
background-color: /* BACKGROUND COLOR HERE*/
}